# JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vps

When I "npm run build" on a vps server with Ubuntu 20.04 64bit
It Show "FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory" It is my memory of vps server not enough?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDoBP.png)

How do I solve this?

Comment: "_How do I solve this?_": Use a VPS instance with more memory

Comment: How much memory does your VPS instance have access to?

Comment: My vps 1gb memory used 33%